# How to get data of specific time period through SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause

I have multiple device IMEIs and they're sending data continuously. There's a table where the time can be seen when a device has sent the last data in the following format: 12/17/2020 4:05:02 PM. Now I want to get those devices which have sent data within last 4 months. I have got the joins but cannot understand the condition I need to make in the `Where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is really flexible about converting strings to date, so you should be able to just `convert()` or `cast()`, and do direct filtering.

So:

```
where convert(datetime, mycol) >= dateadd(month, -4, getdate())
```

This filters on the last 4 months of data, starting from the current date/time. If you want entire months (the current month and the three preceding months)

```
where convert(datetime, mycol) >= dateadd(month, -3, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to get those devices which have sent data within last 4 months.

This sounds like an `exists`.  If you mean 4 months to the day *and* the datetime column is stored correctly as a `datetime`, then:

```
select d.*
from devices d
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.imei = t.imei and
                    t2.datetime >= dateadd(month, -4, getdate())
             );
```

If you mean in the current calendar month or the previous three, then:

```
select d.*
from devices d
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.imei = t.imei and
                    t2.datetime >= dateadd(month, -3, datefromparts(year(getdate(), month(getdate()), 1))
             );
```

If the "datetime" column is stored as a string, then **fix the data**.  Use correct types in the table.  You can convert to a `datetime`, because SQL Server will recognize the format:

```
select d.*
from devices d
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.imei = t.imei and
                    try_convert(datetime, t2.datetime) >= dateadd(month, -4, getdate())
             );
```

However, you should be storing such values using the correct database type.